# Where can I find a simple Tanakh online without verse and chapter numbers?

Tags: tanach

I'm looking for a simple Tanakh online with the original 24 divisions and without chapter or verse numbers. Just want to read it without all the chapter and verse numbers just like in the good old days.

Comment: Do you want it without spaces between words? With punctuation or vowels?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Yaakov and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @rosends with spaces and vowels. I'm not up to reading the text without vowels yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [Tanakh](https://haseforim.org/Tanakh/index.html) It has no chapter or verse numbers. Just the text and the original 24 divisions as you requested.